# Header inset too big, even though I use the `forceInset` prop with insets provided by `react-native-safe-area-context`?

Tags: react-navigation, expo, react-native-safe-area-view

#### Problem

- For some reason, when testing on my older Android phone (Android v 6.0.1), my Expo SDK 36 app's header always has extra padding, looking too bulky, even though the phone has no top notch.
- Testing on an iOS 13.4 simulator for the iPhone 11 with a notch, it handles the notch correctly.

#### Some Debug Results

- When I traverse the component hierarchy in `react-native-debugger`, I see that:
- the `<SafeAreaView />` in my Screen component from `react-native-safe-area-view` has the correct inset values from context, `{ top: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0, right: 0 }`
- However, the `<Header />` component from `react-navigation 4.3.7` has `safeAreaInsets: { top: 'never' }`, when I examine its `props.scene.descriptor.options` to look at its `navigationOptions`
- And further, if I go into `<Header/>`'s children, when I get to `<SafeView/>`, its `props.forceInset.top` is `'always'`.
- I upgraded `react-navigation` today to 4.3.7 from 3.13.0, I'm wondering if there's bugs from earlier versions of dependencies like `react-native-safe-area-context` and `react-native-safe-area-view`, or bugs with them in general.

  - In `package-lock.json`, I notice that there's an `@react-navigation/native` package with a `dependency` of `react-native-safe-area-view` at version `0.14.9` exact, while I notice in `package.json`, I have `react-native-safe-area-view` at semver range `^1.0.0`. I think I installed it via the `expo install` command for packages compatible with your Expo SDK, when first looking into the SafeAreaView instructions in the Expo docs
- My render method looks like this:

```js
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaConsumer>
        {(insets) => {
        console.log("render -> insets", insets)

          return (
            <SafeAreaView
              style={{
                flex: 1,
                backgroundColor: Color.white,
                paddingBottom: insets.bottom,
                paddingLeft: insets.left,
                paddingRight: insets.right,
              }}
              forceInset={insets}
            >
              <View style={MainAppViewContainers.container}>
                ...
              </View>
            </SafeAreaView>
          )
        }}
      </SafeAreaConsumer>
    );
  }
```

#### Possible Explanations Coming To Mind

1. Could `<SafeAreaView/>` fail to automatically detect and set the right insets? [Here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/stack-navigator/#safeareainsets) it says, "By default, the device's safe area insets are automatically detected."
2. Could using the `forceInset` prop on `<SafeAreaView/>` fail to change the `forceInset` prop on `<SafeView>`, which is a child of the `<Header/>` component automatically generated by `react-navigation` once you set the correct header-related `navigationOptions` on screens/navigators?
3. Could there be some kind of dependency clash between the version of `react-native-safe-area-view 0.14.9` used by `@react-navigation/native 3.7.11` which `react-navigation 4.3.7` installed, and `react-native-safe-area-view 1.0.0` installed by Expo?

Comment: Please limit yourself to *one* question per Stackoverflow question.

Comment: Oh sorry! I clarified that the questions were really possible explanations coming to mind, since I'm not sure yet what the problem is. If a reader thinks it's something else entirely, they would be free to ignore them now? Does that help?

Comment: An improvement IMHO.